# What are all the possible codes for {{A\\B}}?

Tags: matrices, brackets

I am interested in the matrix:

[image]

To make this matrix, I am using the following code:

```
$\left\{\!\!\!\left\{\begin{array}{l} A \\ B \end{array}\right\}\!\!\!\right\}$
```

What are other possible codes to make the same matrix?

Comment: Are you asking how to simplify or streamline `\!\!\!`?

Comment: Yes and also if there are any other possible codes beside this which make the same matrix.

Comment: For example, without using \begin and \end {array}

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here are four possibilities. (Note that I've eliminated the whitespace padding around the column vector.)

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath} % for 'Bmatrix' environment

\begin{document}
\[
\left\{ \!\!\! \left\{ \begin{array}{@{}l@{}} A\\B \end{array} \right\} \!\!\! \right\}
\quad
\left\{ \mkern-9mu \left\{ \begin{array}{@{}l@{}} A\\B \end{array} \right\} \mkern-9mu \right\}
\quad
\left\{  \mkern-9mu \begin{Bmatrix} A\\B \end{Bmatrix} \mkern-9mu \right\}
\quad
\biggl\{ \mkern-9mu \begin{Bmatrix} A\\B \end{Bmatrix} \mkern-9mu \biggr\}
\]
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you very much.

Answer (score 10):

I'd define a `BBmatrix` environment modelled on `Bmatrix`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\makeatletter
\newenvironment{BBmatrix}{%
  \left\{\mspace{-8mu}\left\{\env@matrix
}{%
  \endmatrix\right\}\mspace{-8mu}\right\}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\[
\begin{BBmatrix} A \\ B \end{BBmatrix}
\quad
\begin{BBmatrix} A & B \\ C & D \end{BBmatrix}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

With `-9mu` instead of `-8mu` it looks less attractive, in my opinion:

[image]

Different math fonts might need different negative space: experiment by yourself.

Comment: Thank you very much.

Answer (score 8):

Here, with a stack (I took the liberty of kerning `-8mu` rather than `-9mu`):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabstackengine}
\begin{document}
\[\left\{\mkern-8mu\braceVectorstack{A\\B}\mkern-8mu\right\}\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: +1. Observe that `\!\!\!` corresponds to `\mkern-9mu`, though.

Comment: @Mico Yes, I am aware.  Once it gets more than two `\!`, I prefer to just use `\mkern`.  I thought `8mu` looked better than `9mu`.

Comment: Thank you very much.

Answer (score 7):

You can use `\atopwithdelims` TeX primitive:

```
$$ \left\{\mkern-9mu{A \atopwithdelims\{\} B}\mkern-9mu\right\} $$
```

Comment: Thank you very much.